# How to rename multiple .Json files within a subfolder using python and pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, python-os

I am having difficulty trying to rename Json files within a ton of subfolders. What I want to do is to replace json files with a count variable. Since, each and every one of the .json files end with messages_1.json within its respective folder.

Here Person_1, Person_2, Person_3,......,Person_n are individual sub-folders inside the Inbox folder

**Example file structure**

```
- C:/abc/def/ghi/klmn/opq/rst/uvw/xyz/messages/Inbox:
   - Person_1
     - message_1.json
   - Person_2
     - message_1.json
   - Person_3:
      - message_1.json
   .
   .
   .
   .
   - Person_n:
      - message_1.json
```

Additionally, I want to save them as a single panda dataframe and later export it as a csv file where I can work further on the created dataframe.

Here is What I have tried so far and am stuck:

**Code I've Tried**:

```
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/abc/def/ghi/klmn/opq/rst/uvw/xyz/messages/inbox/"):
    
    for name in files:
        
        if name.endswith((".json")):
            folder_names = os.path.relpath(root, directory)
            
            json_files = os.path.join(folder_names, name)
```

**Output Which I want to get**

```
- Person_1
  - message_1.json
- Person_2
   - message_2.json
- Person_3:
  - message_3.json
   .
   .
   .
   .
- Person_n:
 - message_n.json
```

**OR**

```
All replaced json names and then a single csv file with all json files
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated I'm not able to wrap my head around how to get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pathlib` to build the dataframe, then you can rename the files.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

pth = Path("C:/abc/def/ghi/klmn/opq/rst/uvw/xyz/messages/inbox/")

data = [(f, f.parent, f.stem, f.suffix)
        for f in pth.rglob('*.json')]

# load into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['pth', 'dname', 'fname', 'suffix'])

# create new filename
df['new_name'] = (
  df['fname'].str.split('_').str[0] +
  '_' +
  (df.index + 1).astype(str) +
  df['suffix']
)

# now rename each file
for row in df.itertuples():
    row.pth.rename(Path(row.dname) / row.new_name)
```

Comment: can you please also tell me how I can export the now generated json files to a single folder and then extract the keys and values to a csv file? 
(or)
directly export a particular key of json files to a csv
The key I want to export into a csv from all json files is the _messages key_
**Generated keys for the above json file** :: json_data.keys() -> dict_keys(['participants', 'messages', 'title', 'is_still_participant', 'thread_type', 'thread_path'])
**reference link**  [link](https://blr.design/blog/python-multiple-json-to-csv/)